# Visual Studio 2015 repository pattern does not contain defintion for

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I got issues with my repository pattern, it was working this morning so I don't understand here's my code :

IRepository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    List<T> GetAll();
    List<T> GetSome(int index, int pageSize);
    T GetOne(int id);
    T Add(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);            
}
```

IUserRepository :

```
interface IUserRepository : IRepository<User>
{
}
```

UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    public User Add(User entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(User entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return new SchoolContext().User.ToList();
    }

    public User GetOne(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public List<User> GetSome(int index, int pageSize)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(User entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Test File :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var source = new User().GetAll();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Login);
        }

        Console.Read();

    }
}
```

The error I get in the test file is :

> User does not contain a definition for 'GetAll' and no extension
>   method'GetAll' accepting a first argument of type 'User' could be
>   found

I just want to display the list of the login in the console, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: By the way, it looks like there's no point in `IUserRepository`, just make your class directly implement `IRepository<User>`. And if you're using Entity Framework, then you can even make the repository implementation generic, e.g. `context.Set<T>.Where(...)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create repository:

```
var source = new UserRepository().GetAll();
                       ^
```

But you are creating `User` entity instead.

HINT: Instead of creating context each time you call any method on repository, you should pass context to repository and use one context for all operations. Otherwise you will have to attach entities to new context for modification, because entities will not be tracked by new context. And it's better to control lifetime of context to avoid *context disposed* kind of errors when working with lazy-loaded entities.

```
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private SchoolContext db;

    public UserRepository(SchoolContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public List<User> GetAll()
    {
        return db.User.ToList();
    }    
}
```

Event more - you can create base abstract repository `Repository<T>` which will provide such general functionality via method of `Set<T>` from context.

Answer (score 0):

You've simply made a typo. Instantiate a class of type UserRepository where you are instantiating a class of type User and you'll be all set.

```
var repository = new UserRepository();
var users = repository.GetAll();
```